# Pixelheight on UINavigationBar with prompt

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how heigh the UINavigationBar is with the prompt? I know it is 44px without.
Help or link to a website where I can see all the different measurements on the different GUI elements in iPhone is much appriciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Their height is fixed at 44 pixels for portrait mode and
32 pixels for landscape. If you are using a prompt text, then the bar height rises to 74 pixels high.

Answer (score 0):

If you call...

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

...after setting the prompt, it will return the correct ***height*** (which is 74 points).